# Android UI render time

Tags: android, ui-thread, android-anr-dialog, google-console-developer, android-rendering

I got in [Android Vital](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/index.html) a warning that my UI render time is slow.

As they explained in vital page:

> **Frozen UI frames:**
>   Percentage of daily sessions during which users
>   experienced more than 0.1% of frames with a render time greater than
>   700ms. A daily session refers to a day during which your app was used
>   on a device. Google collects the render time of each frame rendered by
>   your app when using the UI Toolkit framework, not when it is using
>   OpenGL directly. Learn more

I can't understand how should I start with this issue.
I took traces of my activities that I suspicion of them but nothing look too strange.

[image]

Comment: Enable `StrictMode` in debug builds to crash your app. 700ms is a fairly long time, and so I/O (disk I/O, network I/O) on the main application thread is a likely culprit.

Comment: Ill enable StrictMode, print to log and update soon. Thanks.

Comment: @motis10: Any valuable findings about this issue?